# update fl_chart by a press of a button

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter code who reads data from a Json file and with the help of the fl_chart package the data are displayed on a chart. On the screen there is also a button. The idea of the button is that when pressed the data are loaded again and the chart would need to rebuild. The problem that i have that pressing the button the chart does not rebuild. Follows the structure of the json:

```
[
    {"day": "Day 1", "value": 10},
    {"day": "Day 2", "value": 20},
    {"day": "Day 2", "value": 25}

  ]
```

Follows the Flutter code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return const MaterialApp(
     home: ChartPage(),
   );
 }
}

class ChartPage extends StatefulWidget {
 const ChartPage({super.key});

 @override
 ChartPageState createState() => ChartPageState();
}

class ChartPageState extends State<ChartPage> {
 List<DataPoint> dataPoints = [];
 Key chartKey = UniqueKey(); // Create a unique key for the chart.

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   loadChartData();
 }

 Future<void> loadChartData() async {
   final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
   final jsonData = json.decode(jsonString);

   List<DataPoint> newDataPoints = [];

   for (var item in jsonData) {
     newDataPoints.add(DataPoint(
       day: item['day'],
       value: item['value'],
     ));
   }

   setState(() {
     dataPoints = newDataPoints;
     chartKey = UniqueKey(); // Update the key to rebuild the chart.
   });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: const Text('Chart Example'),
     ),
     body: Center(
       child: Column(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: <Widget>[
           ElevatedButton(
             onPressed: () {
               loadChartData(); // Reload data when the button is pressed.
             },
             child: const Text('Reload Chart Data'),
           ),
           Expanded(
             child: dataPoints.isNotEmpty
                 ? LineChart(
                     key: chartKey, // Assign the key to the chart.
                     LineChartData(
                       gridData: const FlGridData(show: false),
                       titlesData: const FlTitlesData(show: false),
                       borderData: FlBorderData(show: true),
                       minX: 0,
                       maxX: dataPoints.length.toDouble() - 1,
                       minY: 0,
                       maxY: getMaxYValue(dataPoints),
                       lineBarsData: [
                         LineChartBarData(
                           spots: getDataSpots(dataPoints),
                           isCurved: true,
                           dotData: const FlDotData(show: false),
                         ),
                       ],
                     ),
                   )
                 : const Text('No data available. Press the button to load data.'),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 List<FlSpot> getDataSpots(List<DataPoint> data) {
   return data
       .asMap()
       .map((index, value) => MapEntry(index.toDouble(), FlSpot(index.toDouble(), value.value.toDouble())))
       .values
       .toList();
 }

 double getMaxYValue(List<DataPoint> data) {
   double maxValue = 0;
   for (var point in data) {
     if (point.value.toDouble() > maxValue) {
       maxValue = point.value.toDouble();
     }
   }
   return maxValue + 10; // Add some padding for a better visualization.
 }
}

class DataPoint {
 final String day;
 final int value;

 DataPoint({required this.day, required this.value});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a few experiments with your provided code & I can conclude that you've been facing issues when you re-read the JSON value. It works on the very first time & it won't be working afterwards. It's happening because the root bundle cannot read the value if it changes at the run-time state. The root bundle won't detect the new / updated / most recent value. It'll stuck on the initial value until & unless you perform a hot restart or a hot reload.

So, the solution is to make a Map-type variable and store your data there instead of storing data in a JSON file. Load JSON file is asynchronous (it takes a little bit of time) & getting the value of the class variable is synchronous (won't take time).

I can help you as a technical person if you don't get what I am trying to convey.

Comment: thanks for the help. Instead reading the json from the assets i place the file on a local folder. Like this it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead putting my Json into the assets folder i put it to the local Documents folder. Like this it works and is ok for me.

Follows de code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: ChartPage(),
    );
  }
}

class ChartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChartPage({super.key});

  @override
  ChartPageState createState() => ChartPageState();
}

class ChartPageState extends State<ChartPage> {
  List<DataPoint> dataPoints = [];
  Key chartKey = UniqueKey(); // Create a unique key for the chart.

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadChartData();
  }

  Future<void> loadChartData() async {
    // Get the documents directory
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final filePath = '${directory.path}/data.json';

    try {
      // Read the JSON file from the documents directory
      final jsonString = File(filePath).readAsStringSync();
      final jsonData = json.decode(jsonString);

      List<DataPoint> newDataPoints = [];

      for (var item in jsonData) {
        newDataPoints.add(DataPoint(
          day: item['day'],
          value: item['value'],
        ));
      }

      setState(() {
        dataPoints = newDataPoints;
        chartKey = UniqueKey(); // Update the key to rebuild the chart.
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error reading JSON file: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Chart Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                loadChartData(); // Reload data when the button is pressed.
              },
              child: const Text('Reload Chart Data'),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: dataPoints.isNotEmpty
                  ? LineChart(
                      key: chartKey, // Assign the key to the chart.
                      LineChartData(
                        gridData: const FlGridData(show: false),
                        titlesData: const FlTitlesData(show: false),
                        borderData: FlBorderData(show: true),
                        minX: 0,
                        maxX: dataPoints.length.toDouble() - 1,
                        minY: 0,
                        maxY: getMaxYValue(dataPoints),
                        lineBarsData: [
                          LineChartBarData(
                            spots: getDataSpots(dataPoints),
                            isCurved: true,
                            dotData: const FlDotData(show: false),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Text('No data available. Press the button to load data.'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<FlSpot> getDataSpots(List<DataPoint> data) {
    return data
        .asMap()
        .map((index, value) => MapEntry(index.toDouble(), FlSpot(index.toDouble(), value.value.toDouble())))
        .values
        .toList();
  }

  double getMaxYValue(List<DataPoint> data) {
    double maxValue = 0;
    for (var point in data) {
      if (point.value.toDouble() > maxValue) {
        maxValue = point.value.toDouble();
      }
    }
    return maxValue + 10; // Add some padding for a better visualization.
  }
}

class DataPoint {
  final String day;
  final int value;

  DataPoint({required this.day, required this.value});
}
```